# what is the equivalent in rails3 routes?

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I have used this route in rails 2.3.5 - basically, I wanted to be able to parametrize my controller that I send to the named route.

```
do_action "do_action/:controller" , :action => "do_action"
```

what is the equivalent of this in rails3 routes?

This doesn't work:

```
match "do_action/:controller" , :to => ":controller#do_action", :as => "do_action"
```

thanks

Comment: can u please post the log for more details

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
namespace :do_action do
  resources :controller
end
```

Which will output for a controller named `pages_controller`:

```
do_action/pages
```